# Change the position of listitem in custom listview Android?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, simplecursoradapter

In a Custom listview i have a textview and checkbox. Once the checkbox is checked at any position of the listview that checked position must move under the lastvisibleposition of listview. I checked in the net but i am unable to find the solution. Can anyone give a solution for this, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
int newPos = listView.getLastVisiblePosition() +1;
YourItem item = adapter.getItem(itemPos);
adapter.remove(item);
adapter.addAt(item, newPos);
```

**NOTE**:
You then have to implement an adapter, that provides the `addAt(YourItem item, int newPos)`.  `listView` is your ListView and `itemPos` is the position of the item where the checkbox was checked.

Comment: Ah, I assumed that you use an `ArrayAdapter`. I unfortunately have got no experience with `CursorAdapter`s.. I would assume that you may change the `Cursor` somehow and then set the new `Cursor` with `ist.changeCursor(newCursor)`, but that is only a guess.